# How to update a table data that was created using INNER JOIN based on ID (CASE_KEY )?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, what I want to accomplish are to `UPDATE` the `DEPARTMENT_NAME` from `TV_LABCASE` table and to `UPDATE` the `CHARGE` from `TV_LABCASE` table based on `CASE_KEY`. But I do not know how to update a table that was created using an `INNER JOIN`

`TV_LABCASE` table:

| CASE_KEY | DEPARTMENTMENT_CASE_NUMBER | DEPARTMENT_NAME | CHARGE | LAB_CASE | OFFENSE DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4235 | 090909 | OHIO | STEALING | 0123 | 08/15/2020 |
| 4332 | 131313 | CANADA | STEALING | 764 | 08/17/2020 |

This `TV_LABCASE` table was queried using this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    C.CASE_KEY, C.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER, 
    D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, O.OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION AS CHARGE, 
    LAB_CASE, OFFENSE_DATE
FROM
    TV_LABCASE C
INNER JOIN 
    TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE
INNER JOIN 
    TV_OFFENSE O ON C.OFFENSE_CODE = O.OFFENSE_CODE
ORDER BY 
    CASE_DATE DESC
```

`TV_DEPTNAME` table:

| DEPARTMENT_CODE | DEPARTMENT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | AMERICA |
| 1000 | CANADA |

This `TV_DEPTNAME` table was queried using this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TV_DEPTNAME
```

`TV_OFFENSE` table:

| OFFENSE_CODE | OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| STG | STEALING |
| ABT | ABORTION |

This `TV_OFFENSE` table was queried using this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TV_OFFENSE
```

This is the result in the `TV_LABCASE` table after the update:

| CASE_KEY | DEPARTMENTMENT_CASE_NUMBER | DEPARTMENT_NAME | CHARGE | LAB_CASE | OFFENSE DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4235 | 090909 | New Department Name | New Charge | 0123 | 08/15/2020 |
| 4332 | 131313 | CANADA | STEALING | 764 | 08/17/2020 |

Comment: You use an `UPDATE` statement which the documentation shows how to use with a FROM/JOIN.

Comment: Hi sir @John, That is my problem sir, I do not know how to do an `UPDATE` query in a table created using `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Oh, okay sir @SeanN, Is there a way I can update `DEPARTMENT_NAME` and `CHARGE`?

Comment: As I said, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is very clear.

Comment: Also, we are all equals on this site, so please do not call anyone sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how relational databases work - the table was not created using an INNER JOIN, you wrote a query that is using an INNER JOIN and the values you said you want to change are coming from the joined tables.
What you want to change with your UPDATE is the values in the TV_LABCASE table DEPARTMENT_CODE and OFFENSE_CODE columns.

When you change their values then they will change which rows are joined by query in future, so for example you could write an update like this

```
UPDATE TV_LABCASE 
SET DEPARTMENT_CODE = 100, OFFENSE_CODE = 'ABT' 
WHERE CASE_KEY = 4235
```

That will result in the values shown in your query result changing from OHIO to AMERICA and from STEALING to ABORTION.

Comment: Ok sir, Im gonna try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently i was working on this type of scenario
Please try this query and adjust param according to your requirement.

```
 UPDATE
  ledgers l,
  orders O
 SET
   l.created_at = O.created_at
 WHERE
    l.order_id = O.id;
```